# Razor page foreach to fill grid

Tags: asp.net, razor-pages

I need to loop through an array of objects so that they display on a page three-per-row as below.

```
   <div class="row">

       <div class="col">
           item
        </div>

        <div class="col">
           item2
        </div>

        <div class="col">
            item3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

           <div class="col">
               item4
            </div>

            <div class="col">
               item5
            </div>
            <div class="col">

            </div>

     </div>
```

Normally I would do a foreach loop as below, but I need to divide every three entries with a row.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ItemList)
{
       <div class="col">
            item.Info
        </div>
}
```

What would be a good way of doing this?

Comment: group by index and enumerate the groups

Answer (score 3, accepted):

group the items by index and enumerate the groups to get the desired row

```
@foreach (var row in Model.ItemList
    .Select((item,index) => new { item, index })
    .GroupBy(_ => _.index / 3, _ => _.item)
) {
    <div class="row">
    @foreach(var item in row) {
      <div class="col">
        item.Info
      </div>
    }
    <!-- empty columns -->
    @for(var i = 0; i < row.Count() % 3; i++) {
      <div class="col">
        &nbsp;
      </div>
    }
    </div>
}
```